# Give the following expression in the form of a formula:

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

Does anybody know how to give the following expression in the form of a formula?

> Let $P$ be the set of all people, and let $K$ and $M$ be binary predicates on $P$ with the following interpretation:
>
> $$K(x, y) ~:~ \text{‘x knows y’}$$
>
> $$M(x, y) ~:~ \text{‘x is married to y’}$$

Write the following statement as a formula:

> Everybody who Anna knows is married, except for Bernard.

Comment: Do you mean "Everyone who knows Anna is married" or do you mean "Everyone knows that Anna is married" ?

Comment: The first one: "Everyone who knows Anna is married".

Comment: Ok I'll update your question.

Comment: You'll get more appropriate help if you at least do your best to answer the question on your own first, and write what you get.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

For "Everybody Anna knows is married" :

> $\forall x(K(Anna,x) \rightarrow \exists y M(x,y))$.